# How can I detect that \centering is in effect?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, expl3, justification

I need to detect if the user has typed a \centering before a command. Currently I am detecting it with the following code: Is there an edge case I am missing? Is there a better way and can someone help create a skip_compare:nNnTF l3 function to improve on the code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering
%\raggedright
%\raggedleft
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \centering_bool
\skip_if_eq:nnTF{\rightskip+\rightskip}{0pt plus 2.0fil}{\bool_set_true:N\centering_bool}{\bool_set_false:N\centering_bool}

\bool_if:NTF\centering_bool{TRUE}{FALSE}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\leftskip+\rightskip`? And I would test both of them to be `\@flushglue`. You could additionally test, if `\\ ` is `\@centercr` or `\parindent=\z@` and `\parfillskip=\z@skip`. Depends on how heuristic the test should allowed to be. For a real test, it could also be better to patch `\centering`, `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` (and if available also `\justifing`, `\RaggedRight`, `\RaggedLeft` and `\Centering`).

Comment: You could just test for `\leftskip == \rightskip`, or not? So, maybe just `\bool_set:Nn \l_my_centering_bool { \skip_if_eq_p:nn { \rightskip } { \leftskip } }`.

Comment: @cabohah Generally I try to avoid patching commands or redefining them if I can avoid  it.  Reason I added \leftskip and \rightskip, was to avoid the double boolean test and hence the second part of the question about an l3 function skip_compare, like we have fro dimensions

Comment: @JasperHabicht It will fail on \leftskip=0pt and \rightskip=0pt  try it just after begin document

Comment: Right, I just thought about this the moment you wrote this ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would set the boolean in \centering:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_yannis_centering_bool
\AddToHook{cmd/centering/before}{\bool_set_true:N\l_yannis_centering_bool}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_if:NTF \l_yannis_centering_bool{centering}{no~centering}\par

{\centering \bool_if:NTF 
\l_yannis_centering_bool{centering}{nocentering}\par} 

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would also add a hooks to `\raggedleft` etc. using `\bool_set_false:N`. See my comment to the question.